# Insert element inside another element in the same array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking for a solution for this with no luck. 
I have an JSON object:

```
arr = [
{
    "id": "1",
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": ""
}, 
{
    "id": "2",
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": ""
}, 
{
    "id": "3", 
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": ""   
}, 
{
    "id": "4",
    "dataId" : "1", 
    "rel": ""   
}];
```

I need a way to manipulate this array with javascript (jquery is allowed), so when "arr[a].dataId" match with the "arr[b].id", take "arr[a]" element and insert into "arr[b]" creating a new array like this:

```
newArr = [
{
    "id": "1",
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel" : [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "dataId" : "1"  
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    "id": "2",
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": ""
}, 
{
    "id": "3", 
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": ""   
}
```

];

I hope you understand what I'm asking, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are looking to establish a parent child relation ship within the same array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one does move the elements and doesn't manipulate the array while it's iterating over it. Also doesn't need to extend the Array.prototype. One downside is that you're going to get holes in your array (indexes of elements won't be 0 to length-1), but from what I can see it's not important in your use case.

```
var arr = [
{
    "id": "1",
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": ""
}, 
{
    "id": "2",
    "dataId" : "3", 
    "rel": ""
}, 
{
    "id": "3", 
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": ""   
}, 
{
    "id": "4",
    "dataId" : "1", 
    "rel": ""   
}];

var indexesToMoveMap = {};

$.each(arr, function(outerIndex, outerElem) {
    if (outerElem.dataId) { 
        $.each(arr, function(innerIndex, innerElem) {
            if (innerElem.id === outerElem.dataId) {
                indexesToMoveMap[outerIndex] = innerIndex;
            }
        });
    }
});

$.each(indexesToMoveMap, function(indexToMove, indexToMoveTo) {
    arr[indexToMoveTo].rel = arr[indexToMoveTo].rel || [];
    arr[indexToMoveTo].rel.push(arr[indexToMove]);
    delete arr[indexToMove];
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This works! about the downside... i can live with that :)
As you said in the comments in some case the relationship is in inverse mode (ex: obj 1 mapped to object 4 ) for that reason the other codes doesn't work
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr = [
{
    "id": "1",
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": ""
}, 
{
    "id": "2",
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": ""
}, 
{
    "id": "3", 
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": ""   
}, 
{
    "id": "4",
    "dataId" : "1", 
    "rel": ""   
}];
$(arr).each(function(index,value){
     if(value.dataId)
     {
         $(arr).each(function(ind,val){
             if(val.id==value.dataId)
             {
                 if(val.rel)
                 {
                     val.rel.push({"id":value.id,"dataId":value.dataId});
                 }
                 else
                 {                   
                     val.rel=[{"id":value.id,"dataId":value.dataId}];                     
                 }
             }
         });
     }
});
console.log(arr);
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/7g23B/

Comment: This one doesn't remove the elements from their original place in the array.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
// Array Remove - By John Resig (MIT Licensed)
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
  var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
  this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
  return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};

var arr = [
{
    "id": "1",
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": []
}, 
{
    "id": "2",
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": []
}, 
{
    "id": "3", 
    "dataId" : "", 
    "rel": []   
}, 
{
    "id": "4",
    "dataId" : "1", 
    "rel": []   
}];

var index = 0;
for ( var m = 0; m < arr.length; m++ ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {

       if ( arr[index].id === arr[i].dataId ) {
             arr[index].rel.push (arr[i]);  
             arr.remove(i);
       }

    }
    index++;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4))
```

Comment: this looks close, but it still leaves the child in the parent array. From the example it looks like the OP wants to remove the element once it becomes a child

Comment: @colestrode that's, I believe, an easy fix

Comment: Works! I don't think you need the "index" variable though, couldn't you just use "m"? They should always be equal.

Comment: Good one.. But i don't think it is a good approach to remove the element of the array that you are iterating upon.

Comment: I frequently neglect that. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, this can fail, depending on which elements are mapped to which (or rather, in which order).

Comment: @HannesJohansson can you give a test case that would fail?

Comment: @MilesAlden Yes, for example: use an array with three items and map the first item to the third item. More precisely, it's when any item except the second last is mapped to the last item.

Comment: @MilesAlden Except that scenario, which causes "undefined" error, it can also return an invalid array. Example: Map item 1 to item 4, and item 2 to item 3. Item 1 will not be moved to item 4 in that case. If you try debugging and stepping through the loops I'm sure you'll discover what's wrong.